# I can't log in with a registered user

Tags: python, django, authentication

I can register my users, but I can't log in with these users. After registering the users, they are automatically logged in, so this is the only moment I can access the Profile area. After logging out, I can't log in any user except my superuser.

I have try several ways and can't seem to figure it out.

here are my files:

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin,
)
from django.db import models


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("O endereço de email é obrigatório")
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Cadastro(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from base.models import Cadastro
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class CadastroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Cadastro
        fields = ("username", "email", "password")


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}), required=True
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}), required=True
    )
```

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from base.forms import CadastroForm, LoginForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def inicio(request):
    return render(request, "inicio.html")


def cadastro(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CadastroForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("Cadastrado")
    else:
        form = CadastroForm()
    return render(request, "cadastro.html", {"form": form})

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse(f"Logged in as {user.username}")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Invalid login credentials")
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid form data")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, "login.html", {"form": form})



@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    # Get the logged-in user using request.user
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'user': user})

def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('base:login')  # Redirect to your login page or any other desired URL
```

```
#urls.py 
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "base"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.inicio, name="inicio"),
    path("cadastro/", views.cadastro, name="cadastro"),
    path("login/", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path('profile/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
]
```

```
#template/login.html
{% extends "inicio.html" %}
{% block principal %}


  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Entrar</button>
    </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the return or error message when unable to log in?

Comment: I get the Invalid form data error.

Answer (score 0):

Custom User Model Authentication  should be there in settings.py
and try to check
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.Cadastro'
In your views.py,login_view function, you're using the authenticate method which should work fine if the USERNAME_FIELD and the password are correct
Hope this will work for sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).